# Get events listened by socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am listening to many events on a socket. But when event is fired, the handler function does not get called. I want to check which events are listened by the socket.

```
var socketClient = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = socketClient.connect("server_address_here");
socket.on('event1', function (data) {

});

socket.on('event2', function (data) {

});
```

Are there any functions or properties available?

Comment: Does your sever have matching events?

Comment: did you connect with `socket = io()`? and if so are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I am using socket io client `socket=require('socket.io-client')`. This is build on nodejs. I connect to another socket server and listen for events.

Comment: the io client still needs to connect to the socket server in the same way. Heres an example: https://github.com/agconti/socket.io.tests/blob/master/test/test.js

Comment: I have updated the post to show how I have been making connection. The connection is successful. And even the events I emit are received by server.

Comment: The client versions need to be the same to ensure that they can send and receive events. Can you try `io = require('socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client')` to ensure this is true?

Comment: @jfriend00 its the correct path as of version `1.2.1`.  check out https://github.com/agconti/socket.io.tests for confirmation. why would it be in the root of the package and not in its own separate node module?

Comment: I solved this problem by installing `socket.io-client@0.9.16` and re-installed node and socket with versions matching the server versions of node and socket respectively.

Comment: @jfriend00 if you read above you'll see I was suggesting `require('socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client')` in his serverside code, not serving the file to some front end some where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions of node and socket.io on server(using socket.io-client) should match to the respective versions on socket.io server.

Also, the `socket.io-client@0.9.16` seems to be stable build for this package (as I read in many online references).